# Tooltip for truncated text in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I m working on Angular 2 nd, I created one tooltip that has to open for only truncated text but now it is opening for both truncated text and normal text. So i want to put logic that it will open only on truncated text.  ![enter image descrip

Answer (score 1):

You can have a reference on your wrapping `div` with `@ViewChild('yourDiv') yourDiv: ElementRef`, that probably has the following CSS:

```
width: ...px;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Then compare `clientWidth` and `scrollWidth` with the following expression : `this.yourDiv.nativeElement.scrollWidth > this.yourDiv.nativeElement.clientWidth`

Use this expression to conditionnally display your tooltip

Comment: Thanks! Used your answer to make the solution to similar problem with Angular Material (with `matTooltip` one can address the mentioned check at `matTooltipDisabled` property) - https://stackblitz.com/edit/my-flex-card-name